# IDE does not treat mx:Module descendants as Modules?

Tags: apache-flex, ide, flex3, flexbuilder, module

I'm playing with Modules and they work as advertised: the module swf's ares
built and deployed in the output directories automatically.

My problem is that if I use descendants of mx:Module, the IDE does NOT do all
this nice work for me. I've listed the module in the Flex Modules section of the
project properties, but still nothing.

I'm going to end up repeating a lot of code in each module (to fulfill an
interface) if I cannot figure out how to make the IDE do its thing.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on your project, go to properties and there's a Modules sections. You can add any classes that extends Sprite.

Comment: "I've listed the module in the Flex Modules section of the project properties, but still nothing."

I will try this again carefully.

Comment: I changed the ancestors to AS classes descending from Module instead of starting with a MX Component; that might have helped.

Thanks!